# Proper docker container updates: pull or apt-get upgrade?

Tags: docker

I'm trying to understand what the best way to keep running containers updated in docker. I've been participating in this discussion:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26423515/how-to-automatically-update-your-docker-containers-if-base-images-are-updated/44677829#44677829

And have scripts written that help me see when a new base image is posted on `hub.docker.com` or when there are security updates available for the container here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44677829/925452

The question is, what's the "proper" way to update? I.E. should I be "apt-get upgrading" with:

```
docker exec MYCONTAINER bash -c 'grep security /etc/apt/sources.list > /tmp/security.list; apt-get update > /dev/null; apt-get upgrade -oDir::Etc::Sourcelist=/tmp/security.list'
```

And then doing `docker pull` when a new base-image comes out? How would the `docker pull` impact the updated packages? Maybe I should do the `docker pull` and then follow it with an `apt-get upgrade`?

Comment: Running containers should not be modified, as it opens the door for unexpected changes and drift over time. Instead, just automate your container builds and re-deploy when necessary. Put your containers behind a load balancer and it can be a zero-downtime thing.

Comment: To be clear: containers should be immutable and stateless. Sure, you *can* update running containers, but that doesn't mean that you *should*.

Comment: What if I'm not doing the builds? For instance when using images from docker hub and then docker-compose to start them up? Should I be doing a `docker rmi IMAGE; docker-compose up` to update? And, since that replaces all of the added packages, how would that differ from running `apt-get upgrade` and then doing the `docker rmi IMAGE; docker-compose up` at a later date?

Comment: There seem to be several questions here, some of which have primarily opinion based answers. Can you clarify the question to be a bit more specific?